# Various Twilio Questions related to AMD, ringing detection

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm using Twilio programmable voice to make outbound calls. My use case calls businesses that always have an IVR tree to navigate through. Once you succeed the navigation, you get put on hold, then eventually a real human's line starts ringing, and finally you talk to a human. Here are my questions:

1. I've read that Twilio has an Answering Machine Detection feature. Is this only able to detect specifically answering machine speech? (e.g. please leave your message after the tone) or is AMD able to distinguish between human and machine speech in general? For my use case, I'm trying to figure out some way to distiguish between the robotic IVR tree voice and an actual human voice.
2. Twilio calls also have call status values (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-status-values). Specifically, there is one called "ringing". My question is does "ringing" only occur at the very beginning of the call (for me, before we even hit the IVR)? Or will the status also be "ringing" in the middle of the call if phone ringing occurs? (For example after successfully getting through IVR tree + hold and finally getting a human line).

Thanks.